# alasql- Record Update Issue

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome, alasql, sql.js

I'm Trying to update record on a specific condition.

```
alasql("UPDATE MyDatabase.FooTBL SET Column2 = 1 Where Column1 = 'foo'")
```

It Throws error on console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tables' of undefined(…)

Can anyone suggest the solution how i will update the record.

Comment: Please provide full code to replicate what SQL you are doing...

Comment: alasql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyAtlas.City (city string, population number)');
alasql("INSERT INTO MyAtlas.City Values ('Vienna',894456122)");
@mathiasrw

alasql("UPDATE MyAtlas.City SET city = 'ISLO' Where population = 894456122")

Insert is working put update is not :(

Answer (score 1):

`MyAtlas` does not exist - please use:

```
alasql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS City (city string, population number)'); 
> 1

alasql("INSERT INTO City Values ('Vienna',894456122)");
> 1

alasql("UPDATE City SET city = 'ISLO' Where population = 894456122")
> 1

alasql('select * from City')
> [{"city":"ISLO","population":894456122}]
```

Comment: If it is working for insert then how MyAtlas not exist
Late reply I switched the framework. alasql to [LoveField](https://github.com/google/lovefield)